# How to know selected div ? Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to know which div is selected.
Check my code:

```
        <divdsadsadasda


toggle(i) {
console.log(i) // i got index
}
```

I need to know which div is selected and return values from clicked item.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `(click)="toggle(i)"` replace it with `(click)="toggle(training)"` tht way you'll know which of the trainingExercises was selected.

```
<div *ngFor="let training of data.trainingExercises; let i = index;">
     ...

     <div (click)="toggle(training)">
        ...
     </div>

  
</div>
```